# "Demi-heure" sans article

Tags: usage

Je sais qu'il faut dire :

> Il me faut une demi-heure pour préparer le cours.

Pourquoi ne peut-on dire demi-heure sans l'article ?

> Il me faut demi-heure pour préparer le cours

Comment: Pourquoi voudrais-tu utiliser demi-heure sans article ? Même si en pratique on ne le dit pas mais on pourrait très bien dire *deux demi-heures* pour parler d'une heure, une demi-heure est une unité de mesure, en l’occurrence temporelle, comme toute unité de mesure elle s'accompagne d'un article numérique, un mètre, une année, une heure, une demi-heure.

Comment: On peut le dire: je l'entends même assez couramment dans le midi toulousain. Il est vrai que c'est assez loin de la coupole de l'Institut de France...

Comment: @mouviciel Tu parles de *demi-heure* sans article ou de *deux demi-heures* ?

Comment: @mouviciel C'est vrai, ça s'entend encore un peu aussi dans le Sud-Est. (ex: *Je reviens dans demi-heure*).

Comment: @stbr: je parle de *demi-heure* sans article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un adjectif numéral cardinal a le rôle de déterminant indéfini et se substitue donc à l'article :

> Il me faut **deux** heures pour préparer le cours.

On peut d'ailleurs noter que l'article indéfini ***un*** est aussi un numéral cardinal.

*Demi* n'est pas un adjectif numéral cardinal mais un adjectif classique. Accolé à heure, il forme un nom composé. Un article est alors nécessaire :

> Il me faut **une** **demi**-heure pour préparer le cours.

C'est la même chose avec *quart*:

> Il me faut **un** **quart**-d'heure pour préparer le cours.
>
> Il me faut **trois** **quarts**-d'heure pour préparer le cours.

Answer (score 0):

La raison est que ne sont utilisés en français des déterminants zéro sauf dans des expressions figées et cet exemple ne peut pas être une expression figée. L'[article suivant](https://www.persee.fr/doc/lgge_0458-726x_1991_num_25_102_1602) de Jean-Claude Anscombre, *La détermination zéro : quelques propriétés* , qui examine la nature du déterminant zéro en français, montre qu'il y a quatre classes d'emploi dans lesquelles cela est possible.

[image]

[image]